# How can I run an SSIS package from sql server using an ODBC connection?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am working with an integration services project. From visual studio I have created the SISS packages and they work correctly (it has an ODBC postgreSQL source and an OLE DB destination). But I have problem when I deploy the project to sql server since I run the package from the Integration Services Catalog. It gives me the error that the ODBC connection could not be acquired. Where if I walked is on the Integration Services server, since I imported the package and ran it and it did it without problems. What could be the errors or what could be missing if it works on the server but not on the SISS catalog?

Comment: All of your images aren't in English. [so] is an English speaking community. As they are images (which is frowned upon by the community) we can't even copy them into a translator. If you are posting errors, they need to be as text, and they need to be translated. [Please do not upload images of errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) If you are unable to translate them, then you may want to post your question on a different community in the Stack Exchange Network that speaks your native language.

Comment: I already removed the images. They were to show that one way was successful and the other not

Comment: And now we have no details of what the problem is; making the question unanswerable for different reasons.

Comment: later I will be putting the images in English

Comment: You may have the correct driver installed on one machine and not the other.